# Format linear scale large number replace G to B

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend, data-visualization

I'm trying to format a linear scale of a d3 chart. My y-scale are usually in the billions. I use below code:

```
 const yAxis = g => g
.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
.call(axisLeft(y).ticks(10).tickFormat(format(".2s")))
```

But this gives me units in 'G' instead of 'B' when my y-axis goes into billions.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SroVg.png)

So I replaced the last line of my code with this:

```
    .call(axisLeft(y).ticks(10).tickFormat(format(".2s").replace("G","B")))
```

But I got a typeError: ×

> TypeError: Object(...)(...).replace is not a function

I also tried this:

```
    .call(axisLeft(y).ticks(10).tickFormat((d, i)=>format(".2s")(data[i].value).replace("G", "B")))
```

But my ticks become no longer 'nice()' and the order is all messed up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S23hp.png)

How can I replace my unit from 'G' to 'B'? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `format("2s")` is a function that returns a string, while `replace` should be called on the string itself.

Therefore, it should be:

```
.call(axisLeft(y).ticks(10).tickFormat(d => format(".2s")(d).replace("G","B")))
```

Here, `format(".2s")(d)` returns the formatted string according to the tick. Finally, your second snippet almost got it right, but you're ignoring the actual scale-generated ticks by using only the ticks' indices to get the data values.

Comment: That is very helpful you followed up by pointing out that I was ignoring the scale-generated ticks. I misunderstood the format as I thought it applies to all y values. Thank you!